# How to use systemwide kernel in miniconda environment

Tags: makefile, command-line, miniconda

I have been trying to run a code using `make ../logs/output.html` in the command line. It should run a .ipynb notebook (that use R/4.2.1) and convert it into a .html file in an logs folder.

When running the code, it returns the error "no such kernel named ir42". This means that the notebook does not read the systemwide IRkernel 4.2 --- indeed this does not appear if I check the kernel specifications using `jupyter kernelspec list`. Is there a way to make sure that my miniconda environment reads the systemwide kernels?